# Lambda node.js function with videothumbnails

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, video-thumbnails

I'm relatively new to AWS Lambda, and I need to develop a Lambda function that uses ffmpeg for creating thumbnails from video. I have uses few packages, but with every one I get errors, usually with starting the process for ffmpeg.

Package I have used so far: [link](https://concrete5.co.jp/blog/creating-video-thumbnails-aws-lambda-your-s3-bucket)

Could someone provide me with some useful tutorial on how to develop this kind of function?

I'd appreciate any type of help.

Regards,
Katerina

Answer (score 0):

Few, possibly none, of the ffmpeg wrapper libraries actually include ffmpeg itself. You need to supply the ffmpeg/ffprobe binaries yourself ([here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) or [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-binaries)), in addition to the ffmpeg wrapper (e.g. [node-fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg)), and your code.

As an aside, if these are large videos, then you may want to take a look at [Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/). You can set this up to be event-driven on video files being uploaded to S3 where your Lambda function starts a trancoding pipeline that emits image frames or thumbnails.

Comment: Hello. I followed your advice. and installed fluent-ffmpeg and ffmpeg/ffprobe binaries. How ever I'm getting an error when I run my code on Lambda that it can not find ffprobe tho I set ffmpeg.setFfprobePath. Since it's not on local machine but rather on Aamazon, how should exactly I define the path where the ffprobe binary is stored? Many thanks